# In software projects there are version numbers how do I do that for my Java project at Eclipse in automatic way?

Tags: svn, subclipse, version-numbering

In software projects there are version numbers how do I do that for my Java project at Eclipse in automatic way ?

I'm using Subclipse will it help me set the application version number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use build tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague

Version numbers(or in subversion parlance 'change sets') are generated whenever you make a 'commit' to the repository.  If you wish to produce a simpler version number(sometimes called a 'release' number(i.e.  release 1.0, release 1.1 etc) you can do this by generating a 'tag' which is merely a copy of a given change set and given a label(see [tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html)).  In Eclipse you can do this with the 'Team => Branch/Tag...' item found when you right click on your project in the package explorer.

If you're not familiar with the practice, I would suggest that you create a 'fake' or dummy project/repository to actually practice this on.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a project management tool like Maven or Gradle to build your application. These build tools will provide a version number.